# Angularjs directive 2 way binding not working + delay issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having the following problem. I have a `search.js` controller which uses a template `results.html`. That template uses a **category directive** to show all categories that any of the company products might have (as a sidebar). It also uses multiple **product carousel** directives to show the products of each matching company.

In my `search.js` controller I define a scope variable named `filterCategoryId` which starts at null. This variable is bound to the categories directive as well as all product carousel directives. Which makes me expect that a change to this variable in either any of the directives as well as in the `search.js` controller would propagate to all others using this variable. The variable is used to limit the display of products to only those of that category.

But on my product carousel directive, I have defined a scope method `removeFilterCategory()` which sets `filterCategoryId` back to null. It works within its own scope. I can see the effects. But it does not effect the `filterCategoryId` on the categories directive. I can tell because I use ng-class to set an `active` class to the list item mentioning the category id to which the products are filtered. But changing `filterCategoryId` on the categories directive **does** propagate to the product carousel directives. *There is an ng-repeat before the product carousel directives...*

In essence. The variable was first defined on the scope of my controller. If I change it on the categories directive, the change gets propagated (after a noticeable while) to the product carousel directives. But if I change it from any of the product carousel items, the categories directive does not reflect the changes. And I don't see why. *The product carousel uses a $watch to check `filterCategoryId` and recalculate its rows..*

All directives use an isolated scope with the same variable `filterCategoryId` and use `'='` as scope value.

What could be the issue?

And secondary even if I change `filterCategoryId` on the categories directive, it takes 5-6sec to reflect changes on the product carousel directives.

I'm feeling I'm missing something here. Either I have an obvious code error I seem to overlook or I'm missing some angular understanding :). Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest explicitly telling AngularJS to register the change using `$scope.apply( function(){/*change var here*/});` , see the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope).

There is a nice article explaining the details of Angular's digest cycle: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

This seems to be the main problem if you are experiencing delays though I also suggest ensuring that the variable `filterCategoryId` is *always* an object, so it is never passed as a copy, maybe change it to `filter.CategoryId` etc.

Comment: Aha your second suggestion seems to help me a lot. Binding primitive values seems to be a no-no. When I use an object, changes are propagated everywhere. Many thanks!

I'll look into delay issue tomorrow. This seems to persist. My feeling says it has something to do with the digest cycle.

Comment: Well after some testing I discovered my delay problem is caused by the bootstrap carousel js. If I use plain html with no js attached. The dom update is almost instantly which is perfect. But when applying the carousel, there is a very noticeable delay in updating the dom. But this is a seperate issue, I'll look into it tomorrow.